# Efficiently finding $k$th derivative of power of rational function

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Suppose I have the rational function
$$g(x) = \frac{x+c+2cx}{1-cx}$$
where $c$ is some constant and I want to find the $k$th derivative of $f(x)=(g(x))^n$ at $x=0$. I know that this is feasible for very small $k,n$ using product rule repeatedly since the $k$th derivative of $g$ itself is relatively simple; $g^{(i)}(x)$ can be easily found from writing $g(x)$ as
$$g(x) = 2-\frac1c-\frac{1/c+c+2}{x-\frac1c}$$
which is easy to work with. But when $n,k$ are larger, the product becomes an annoying sum:
$$\left(g(x)^n\right)^{(k)}=\left(ng(x)^{n-1}\cdot g'(x)\right)^{(k-1)}=\left(n(n-1)g(x)^{n-2}\cdot g'(x)+ng(x)^{n-1}\cdot g''(x)\right)^{(k-2)}$$
and it seems to only get worse from there. Obviously we're able to extract a factor of $n$ or something but that doesn't really seem to help. Once it's properly expanded, it should be easy just to substitute in $c$ for $g(0)$ and $-\frac{(-1)(-2)\cdots (-i+1)\left(1/c+c+2\right)}{\left(-\frac1c\right)^i}$ in for $g^{(i)}(0)$, so the finish should not be too bad. I was thinking maybe it's possible to force some "combinatorial" identity. Any tips? Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried binomial expansion on your first rearrangement of $g(x)$?  Each term of that expansion will be a pure power of $x-1/c$, so its $k$th derivative is very simple and you only need $n+1$ terms (one less for $k\ge 1$ as the constant term will vanish).

Comment: Using that, I'm getting that the desired derivative is 
$$\text{some constant stuff}\cdot \sum_{i=0}^n\binom ni \left(\frac{c(c^2+2c+1)}{2c-1}\right)^i \frac{(i+k-1)!}{(i-1)!}$$
but this is still not particularly appealing, and I do not see a way to get to a closed form (but this might not exist). Is it possible to coax this into a binomal-theorem like form?

Comment: Well, that sounds a far sight better than what you had before (indeed, your result is nicer than the existing answer), and can easily be computed in linear time :).  WolframAlpha tells me this is a hypergeometric function.  Maybe it can be simplified or computed rapidly: a lot of people have studied this sort of thing, but I am not one of them.

Answer (score 1):

You might try using [Faa di Bruno's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fa%C3%A0_di_Bruno%27s_formula).

$$ \dfrac{d^k}{dx^k} g(x)^n = \sum_{\pi \in \Pi} \frac{n!}{(n-|\pi|)!} g(x)^{n - |\pi|}
\prod_{B \in \pi} g^{(|B|)}(x) $$
where $\Pi$ is the set of partitions of $\{1,\ldots,k\}$ of cardinality at most $n$, $|\pi|$ is the cardinality of the partition $\pi$, and $|B|$ is the cardinality of the block $B$.